# Why doesn't drawing onto the hdc immediately update the window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

According to [this website](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/bitmaps.html), any drawing operation performed on the HDC returned by BeginPaint will immediately display on the screen. However, the number printed by the following code only updates when the window is resized:

```
int counter = 0;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            std::string s = std::to_string(counter).c_str();
            TextOutA(hdc, 0, 0, s.c_str(), s.length());
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        counter++;
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Even when continuously sending WM_PAINT to the window with

```
RedrawWindow(hwndMain, 0, 0, RDW_INTERNALPAINT);
```

after EndPaint, the number only updates when the window is resized. How can I get the number to update without manually resizing the window?

Comment: We need a [mcve]. Where perhaps we will see your message loop. If you have one.

Comment: Are you calling InvalidateRect(hWnd, nullptr, FALSE); and UpdateWindow(hWnd); ? That's how one usually triggers WM_PAINT.

Comment: Do you know that you have actually been sent a WM_PAINT message?

Comment: [According to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-redrawwindow), you could have tried at least 3 flags other than `RDW_INTERNALPAINT`.  Did you do that, and if you did, did you get the same results?

Comment: `WM_PAINT` is triggered only when the window needs to be repainted. Simply updating the `counter` variable is not enough, you have to explicitly signal the window to then repaint itself so it can draw the new `counter` value. Using `InvalidateRect()` is usually preferred, as it allows the OS to decide when to trigger `WM_PAINT`. However, using `UpdateWindow()` or `RedrawWindow()` can force an immediate repaint, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Calling RedrawWindow with different flags solved the problem.
Specifically `RedrawWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, RDW_FRAME | RDW_INVALIDATE);` after `counter++;`